# CrashPlan don't cross filesystem boundaries

Tags: linux, backup, filesystems, mount, crashplan

I have replaced my `backuppc` to CrashPlan Family. CrashPlan is very feature-full, but I can not force backup to **do not cross filesystem boundaries**, like `rsync -x`. It would be a killing feature, because now, I have to exclude all path of bind mount like mounts by hand.

**Have anyone a reasonable solution or workaround for this?**

*The deduplication is not an answer, because the `inotify` will alert twice, and CrashPlan will backup twice too. Specified paths one-by-one and regexp excludes are quite similar, because when I mount a new resources I could forget exclude this.*

Answer (score 0):

This documentation article might shed some light:
http://support.code42.com/CrashPlan/Latest/Configuring/Using_Soft_And_Hard_Links_With_CrashPlan

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link, as the answer can become invalid if the linked page changes or the target site is unreachable/permanently offline.

Comment: @CrashPlan: I have read this article, but I had not found any information about the CrashPlan do not cross filesystem boundaries.